# Python 2.7 Slot Machine if statement issue

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import random
numbers = []
wheel1 = 0
wheel2 = 0
wheel3 = 0
winnings = int(0)
balance = int(50)

def generator(balance):

    number1 = random.random()
    number2 = random.random()
    number3 = random.random()

    if number1 < 0.05:
        wheel1 = "Cherry"
    elif number1 < 0.15:
        wheel1 = "Diamond"
    elif number1 < 0.30:
        wheel1 = "Hearts"    
    elif number1 < 0.65:
        wheel1 = "Spade"    
    elif number1 < 1:
        wheel1 = "Monkey"  

    if number2 < 0.05:
        wheel2 = "Cherry"
    elif number2 < 0.15:
        wheel2 = "Diamond"
    elif number2 < 0.30:
        wheel2 = "Hearts"    
    elif number2 < 0.65:
        wheel2 = "Spade"    
    elif number2 < 1:
        wheel2 = "Monkey"

    if number3 < 0.05:
        wheel3 = "Cherry"
    elif number3 < 0.15:
        wheel3 = "Diamond"
    elif number3 < 0.30:
        wheel3 = "Hearts"    
    elif number3 < 0.65:
        wheel3 = "Spade"    
    elif number3 < 1:
        wheel3 = "Monkey"

    return wheel1
    return wheel2
    return wheel3

def win(generator,balance):

    generator(balance)

    if wheel1 =="Monkey"and wheel2 == "Monkey"and wheel3 == "Monkey":
        print "JACKPOT!"
        winnings = int(50)
        balance + winnings
        print 'JACKPOT!'

    else:
        print 'noice'
        winnings = int(10)
        balance + winnings
        print 'noice'

    return balance


print "Welcome to the International Slot Machine"
print ""
print "Balance: $",balance
print ''
spinyn = (raw_input("Would you like to spin? $5 per spin. Enter y or n:\n"))
while True:
    if spinyn == "y":
        break
    elif spinyn == "n":
        print "Final Balance: $",balance
        print "Thank you for using the International Slot Machine"
        raise SystemExit
    else:
        spinyn = raw_input('\033[31mPlease enter only y or n.\033[0m\n')    
spin = (raw_input("Press enter to spin for $5:\n"))
while True:
    if spin == '':
        balance = balance - 5
        if balance <= 0:
            print ""
            print "Final Balance: $",balance
            print "You have run out of money, the game has now ended."
            raise SystemExit
        print ""
        print "\033[34mResult:\033[0m"
        print "\033[34m-------\033[0m"
        balance = generator(balance)
        print ""
        print win(generator,balance)
        print "New balance:$",balance
        print ""
        spinagain = (raw_input("Would you like to spin again? Press enter to spin again, type anything to exit.\n"))
        while True:
            if spinagain == "":
                break
            else:
                print "Final Balance: $",balance
                print "Thank you for using the International Slot Machine"
                raise SystemExit
    else:
        spin = (raw_input("Please press enter to spin.\n"))
```

I appreciate any suggestions about the method of selecting a random symbol, but please withhold as there is only one question I have. My question is: In the win function, how do I make it recognise the 3 wheel outputs. I've done what I thought would work however it does not, even when I land on 3 monkeys.

Any other suggestions are welcome. But please keep in mind that is the most important.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What does `generator` do in your `win` function?

Comment: `import random; random.choice(('Cherry', 'Diamond', 'Hearts', 'Spade', 'Monkey'))`. If you do `choices = ('Cherry', 'Diamond', 'Hearts', 'Spade')` then it's even better.

Comment: ozgur beat me to an answer. As for suggestions for the generator, my only thought is that you have a lot of repeating code. It would be easier to maintain your code if you had a function to compute a wheel's value based on the random value rather than copying and pasting for each wheel.

Comment: @WayneWerner: That doesn't give the same result. random.choice will randomly choose any of the choices, without weighting. Scott's implementation weights outcomes differently (e.g., cherry is pretty unlikely).

Comment: @bmhkim good catch. That can be remedied by putting more or less values in your choices though, e.g. `('Cherry', 'Diamond', 'Diamond', 'Hearts', 'Hearts', 'Hearts')`.

Comment: @bmhkim That is exactly right bmhkim, I cannot have random choice as having the same chance between cherry and monkey is illogical.

Comment: @WayneWerner Sort of. What if you need Cherry to come up 23.2232% of the time?

Comment: @bmhkim Yeah, for that case you would need something a little bit more complicated.

Comment: @WayneWerner I think that even in the presented case, your solution is suboptimal. Probability for Cherry: 5%, Diamond: 10%, Hearts: 15%, Spade: 35%, Monkey 35%. Your proposal would require a list (or tuple) that is 20 items long, with each occurrence of an item representing a 5% probability, and with two choices repeating 7 times each. Not great, in my opinion. Plus, when you want to adjust probabilities, you're stuck counting off how many of each item is in the list, as well as the full size of the list in order to determine what the current implementation does.

Comment: @ozgue Where did your answer go?

Comment: @ScottMiller he deleted it

Comment: Your extensive edit to the code have rendered both existing answers irrelevant. The `spin` and `win` functions look OK at first glance, what are your exact symptoms now?

Comment: @MarkRansom I have returned the code to the original. Please check it. All I want it to do is recognise wheel 1,2 and 3 as whatever I want it to recognise. There is no error, just when Monkey is returned 3 times, the if statement doesn't recognise it. Also I currently get the cannot concatenate str and int error in balance + winnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you have here is that your concept of scope needs a little help.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/344286) is a really good start.

To make a short example of your code, let's just do this:

```
def generator(balance):
    wheel_1 = 'Monkey'
    wheel_2 = 'Diamond'
    wheel_3 = 'Heart'

    return wheel_1, wheel_2, wheel_3


def win(generator):
    print wheel_1, wheel_2, wheel_3

win(generator)
```

What you'll get here is a `NameError`, because `wheel_1` (and 2 & 3) don't actually exist within the `win` function. They only exist within the generator function. So what you need to do is get the values *from* the generator function, and put them somewhere that 'win' can see. You can actually do this pretty easily, since we're already returning the values from the `generator` function:

```
# Note: generator was removed as a parameter.
# We don't need it here, because if Python
# can't find the name `generator` it will look
# in the enclosing scope and find the function
# `generator` there.
def win():
    # What we want to do is *call* `generator` and 
    # assign the results to some variables that *are*
    # in `win`'s scope
    wheel_1, wheel_2, wheel_3 = generator()
    print wheel_1, wheel_2, wheel_3
```

---

As you mentioned, you can definitely improve some things in your current code. You've noticed inside your `generator` function there's code that looks almost exactly the same. When you look at code and you get that feeling, that's what's called a "code smell". That's what happens when your (sub)conscious mind sees some code that it knows could be improved. In this particular case there's a principle called **DRY** - **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself.

You can replace your existing code with the following:

```
def spin_one():
    number = random.random()

    if number < 0.05:
        result = 'Cherry'
    elif number < 0.15:
        result = 'Diamond'
    elif number < 0.30:
        result = 'Hearts'
    elif number < 0.65:
        result = 'Spade'    
    else:
        result = 'Monkey'

    return result

def generator():
    return spin_one(), spin_one(), spin_one()
```

And what I might even do is remove the generator call altogether and simply do this:

```
if all((spin_one() == 'Monkey' for _ in xrange(3))):
```

You can read the docs on [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all).

Though, if you want to have more than just win a lot and win a little, then you'd need to keep the values:

```
wheels = [spin_one() for _ in xrange(3)]
```

Then you can do:

```
if all(wheel == 'Monkey' for wheel in wheels):
    # Alternatively, wheels.count('Monkey') == 3
    print 'Jackpot'
elif wheels.count('Hearts') == 2:
    print 'Win'
elif all(wheel == 'Lemon' for wheel in wheels):
    print 'You lose'
```

And any other kind of winning you might want to add.

**Prompt**

I don't think this is either better or worse than your current prompt approach, but I used to use it all the time in my C++ course.

```
def prompt():
    choice = raw_input('(Y)es or (N)o: ').lower()
    if choice == 'y':
        return True
    elif choice == 'n':
        return False
    else:
        print '**ERROR** Please input "y" or "n"'
        return prompt()
```

It's a nice, simple way to get a handle on recursion :)

Comment: `def win(balance):
    wheel_1, wheel_2, wheel_3 = generator(balance)
    if wheel1 == wheel2 == wheel3 == "Monkey":
        print "JACKPOT!"
        winnings = 50
        balance = balance + winnings
        print 'JACKPOT!'`

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format it correctly as a comment.

Comment: @ScottMiller is there any reason you're passing `balance` to your generator? Unless balance is going to affect your odds, you shouldn't need it there. And yeah you can't do multiline comments ;)

Comment: @ScottMiller what problem do you still have?

Comment: @ScottMiller Your win function returns None, so print win() will just print None.  You don't seem to be updating balance anywhere.  Also, there are only three outcomes that produce any sort of result (as indicated by the printing in the win function.)  Is that want you want?

Comment: @WayneWerner It returns "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable". Its got something to do with wheels = [spin() for _ in xrange(3)].

Comment: Ah, you have a variable named `spin`. You need to rename your function, the string input... or you could just get rid of that variable and the check for` ''`